# how to change xml tag format like <xml></xml> to <xml/>

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

I have a xml file. As per my requirement I need to update empty tag such as I need to change `<xml></xml> to <xml/>`. Is it possible to change the tags like that..

Thank you...

Comment: It depends how you are creating your xml file in the first place... A code snippet would be useful

Comment: Already I created the xml file. I need to edit the empty tags from <xml><xml/> to <xml/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xmlString="<xml></xml> <toto></toto>";
var properString=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(xmlString, "<([^>]+)></[^>]+>", "<$1/>");
```

EDIT: explanation!

@Neil Knight has already provided, in a comment, [a link to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) explaining the concept of regular expressions. The part specific to .NET is available here: [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

A starting XML tag can be matched with the following regular expression: `<[^>]+>`. The `[^>]+` part can be read as: all characters that are not ">", with at least one character (so `<>` is not matched but `<a>` is). An ending XML tag can be matched with the same kind of expression: `</[^>]+>` (note the slash after the first character). So the regular expression `<[^>]+></[^>]+>` matches empty tags such as `<foo></foo>` (but be careful, it also matches `<foo></bar>` which is not valid XML code).

What we need now is to isolate the characters between "<" and ">". For that, we use parenthesis: `<([^>]+)>`. This instructs the regular expression engine to capture the matched characters. Each group of parenthesis can be referred later in a replacement operation by the "$x" string (where "x" is a number: "$1" for the first matching parenthesis, "$2" for the second one, etc.).

So, with a call to `Regex.Replace(xmlString, "<([^>]+)></[^>]+>", "<$1/>")`, `<foo></foo>` will be replaced by `<foo/>` ("foo" characters are captured, and "$1" is replaced by them). `<foo></bar>` will also be replaced by `<foo/>`.

I hope that this explanation is enough for @Felix K. ;o)
(my English is not so good, that's why I did not provide many details)

Comment: Some links to reg-ex explanation and a short description and i give you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (someElement.innerText == string.Empty) 
{ 
    someElement.innerText = null; 
}
```

Comment: This requires a XmlDocument right? Please put a bit more time in a answer.

Comment: Typing the above on a mobile phone touchscreen was exhausting enough for me. :-P

Comment: I wonder what offers the best performance: a regular expression or a complete traversal of the XmlDocument? In terms of code simplicity, regular expression is better: only one line of code to process the whole document.